# How to create jCheckbox in jTable when retrieve data from SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, jtable, jcheckbox

I'm using netbeans and i connect it with SQLite database, below you will find the code which i use to fill the jtable from the database, the problem is that the status column ((third column)) shows me the boolean value as 1s and 0s how can i make it as a jcheckboxs inside the jtable?

```
private void Update_table() {

    try {
        String sql = "select Name,location,Status from Items where E_ID =" + 
                Integer.parseInt(E_I.getText());

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        jtable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Now i use this but the checkboxs never get checked!! the color of the row is changed and the checkbox is appears at the column wich i want but the problem is how to make it checked if true!!

```
    public class CheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

      CheckBoxRenderer() {
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
      }

      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
          boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isSelected) {

          setSelected(true);

        } else {

          setSelected(false);
        }

        return this;
      }
      }  








   public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final java.awt.Component cellComponent =    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        Object val = table.getValueAt(row, 2);
        String sval = val.toString();

        int ival = Integer.parseInt(sval);
        if (ival == 0) {
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.magenta);

        } else {
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
            cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
        if (isSelected) {
            cellComponent.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            cellComponent.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }
       CheckBoxRenderer checkBoxRenderer = new CheckBoxRenderer();
       Itabel.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(checkBoxRenderer);
        return cellComponent;

        }

         }
```

Comment: As a side note, use prepared statements to build your queries to avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Look up "default cell renderer" - I think that's the thing that you need.  I don't know enough of the details off the top of my head to write you a good answer.  But if I have time later, and nobody else answers, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering is achieved through the use of a combination of look ups in the `JTable`, keyed to a given `Class` type and a `TableCellRenderer`.

The `JTable` will ask the `TableModel` for the `columnClass` and will look up a `TableCellRenderer` to use for that given type.

By default, when `TableModel#getColumnClass` method returns `Boolean.class`, the `JTable` will use a `JCheckBox` to render the given value.

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [SOLVED - setting the data of the next column in jtable in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403595/solved-setting-the-data-of-the-next-column-in-jtable-in-java/23405029?noredirect=1#comment35864757_23405029) for two examples