# How can i add checkbox on my JTable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

This is a Drag and Drop Java Swing

Here's my code

```
prod.removeColumn(prod.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));

    String sql = "select prod_id,prod_description,prod_wh_name,prod_fr_name from product order by prod_description asc";
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        Object[] row = new Object[columns];
        for(int i = 1 ; i <=columns;i++)
        {
            row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        ((DefaultTableModel) prod.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() -1,row);
    }
```

I want to add a checkbox on the left side of every data in jtable(Prod Description), Any solution for that? and can select more than one? and how can i get the data of the selected item? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest starting with [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and maybe some searching which might turn examples like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822376/display-jcheckbox-in-jtable/23822410#23822410) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403595/solved-setting-the-data-of-the-next-column-in-jtable-in-java/23405029?noredirect=1#comment35864757_23405029) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099717/how-to-add-jcheckbox-in-jtable/18099876#18099876) and then I'd try something

Comment: I'll try your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest to remove `mysql` tag, It is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @c0der Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a "wrapper" TableModel.

In this example a column containing check marks will be added to the left of the columns in any existing TableModel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class CheckBoxWrapperTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private String columnName;

    public CheckBoxWrapperTableModel(DefaultTableModel model, String columnName)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.columnName = columnName;

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
            checkBoxes.add( Boolean.FALSE );
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column)
    {
        return (column > 0) ? model.getColumnName(column - 1) : columnName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return model.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return model.getColumnCount() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
    {
        if (column > 0)
            return model.getValueAt(row, column - 1);
        else
        {
            Object value = checkBoxes.get(row);
            return (value == null) ? Boolean.FALSE : value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        if (column > 0)
            return model.isCellEditable(row, column - 1);
        else
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column)
    {
        if (column > 0)
            model.setValueAt(value, row, column - 1);
        else
        {
            checkBoxes.set(row, (Boolean)value);
        }

        fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        return (column > 0) ? model.getColumnClass(column - 1) : Boolean.class;
    }

    public void removeRow(int row)
    {
        checkBoxes.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        model.removeRow(row);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        //  Create the table with check marks in the first column

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            model.setValueAt("" + i, i, 0);
        }

        CheckBoxWrapperTableModel wrapperModel = new CheckBoxWrapperTableModel(model, "Select");
        JTable table = new JTable(wrapperModel);

        //  Add button to delete selected rows

        JButton button = new JButton( "Delete Selected Rows" );
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                for (int i = table.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    Boolean selected = (Boolean)table.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    System.out.println(selected + " : " + i);

                    if (selected)
                    {
                        wrapperModel.removeRow(i);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
        frame.add( button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

This allows you to add the check box even if you don't have access to the original TableModel when it is created to add your own column of check boxes.

Comment: I'll try to learn this wrapper thingy. Thanks! One more question, can i use this wrapper thingy to be able to get the data like the prod_id on the original table?